# Почему не работает выпадающее меню в мобильной версии сайта WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В консоли ошибка не отображается, может кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой?

```
<nav class="navbar">
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
<span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
<a href="/" rel="home" class="logo"><img height="44" src="/wp-content/themes/valiuswp/images/studio-2x.png"></a>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
<li><a href="#our-services">Features</a></li>
<li><a href="#pricing">Pricing</a></li>
<li><a href="#about-us">About</a></li>
<li><a href="/blog/">Blog</a></li>
<li><a href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<li><a href="/my-account/">My Account</a></li>
<li><a class="header-signup-link" href="/signup/">Sign Up</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: добавьте хотя бы ссылку на сайт) или больше описания (js, html)?

Comment: добавила к описанию элемент html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вы указываете неверные дата атрибуты. подробнее о созданиии навигации вы можете прочитать здесь https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/

в вашем случае кнопка должна выглядеть вот так

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное!